# How to subscribe on JMS topic through Mule?

Tags: mule, jndi, mule-studio

I need to subscribe to a JMS topic through Mule. We're using Mule 3.5

I have setup this flow:

```
<jms:connector name="vos-jms-connector" specification="1.1"
    validateConnections="true"
    connectionFactoryJndiName="ConnectionFactory"
    doc:name="JMS" password="guest" username="guest">
    <jms:custom-jndi-name-resolver
        class="org.mule.transport.jms.jndi.CachedJndiNameResolver">
        <spring:property name="jndiInitialFactory"
            value="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" />
        <spring:property name="jndiProviderUrl" value="jnp://xx.xx.16.41:1099" />
    </jms:custom-jndi-name-resolver>
</jms:connector>

<flow name="vcm-vos-vpo-topic" doc:name="vcm-vos-vpo-topic">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="VPOtopic"
        connector-ref="vos-jms-connector" doc:name="VPOtopic" responseTimeout="4000" />
    <logger message="request for topic" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

When I run the Mule project I would expect that I can connect to the topic with the following java code (this runs in another project, on the same machine):

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099");
    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    props.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext(props);
    TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
    Topic vpoTopic = (Topic) context.lookup("VPOtopic");
```

However, I get a "Coneection Refused" exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 127.0.0.1:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server /127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server /127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1828)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:717)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:710)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at nl.triopsys.vcm.vos.jmsmock.Main.getInitialContext(Main.java:132)
    at nl.triopsys.vcm.vos.jmsmock.Main.main(Main.java:65)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server /127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server /127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:359)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:284)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1798)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server /127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:329)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:82)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:325)
    ... 7 more
```

How do I connect to the inbound-endpoint on my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using the JNDI service? 
Tipically, you don't need to set the full name on the topic attribute, just use the name:

Although is weird to read from a topic and write to the same topic.

Comment: Victor, thanks for your answer, I think i'm a little closer, please see my edit.

Comment: You jnp service in 127.0.0.1:1099 looks closed for external conections. Is it possible that works for your other project because that code stands on the same container that hosts the jndi?
Could you try telnet 127.0.0.1 1099?

Comment: Thank you. After opening the port, the same exception occurs. Telnet connection is also refused, but that's due to fact that you can't telnet to localhost. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to telnet fromt he same host where Mule runs to the host that have the jnp service.